# Potential race condition for a simple multiple threading program

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program that consists of three threads. Each thread is passed in an object `Foo` and no matter which thread calls which function, the output for the program will always be `"firstsecondthird"`. I use semaphore and I'm writing the test code for my implementation. Sometimes, my test case passed but sometimes the test case failed:

```
input: [1,2,3] = firstsecond
Assertion failed: (false), function test, file /home/foo/printInOrder.cc, line 100.
Abort trap: 6
```

My program looks like below:

```
#include "cpputility.h"
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printFirst()
{
  cout << "first" << std::flush;
}

void printSecond()
{
  cout << "second" << std::flush;
}

void printThird()
{
  cout << "third" << std::flush;
}

class Foo
{
protected:
  sem_t firstJobDone;
  sem_t secondJobDone;

public:
  Foo()
  {
    sem_init(&firstJobDone, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&secondJobDone, 0, 0);
  }

  void first(function<void()> printFirst)
  {
    printFirst();
    sem_post(&firstJobDone);
  }

  void second(function<void()> printSecond)
  {
    sem_wait(&firstJobDone);
    printSecond();
    sem_post(&secondJobDone);
  }

  void third(function<void()> printThird)
  {
    sem_wait(&secondJobDone);
    printThird();
  }
};

void test()
{
  unordered_map<int, pair<void (Foo::*)(function<void()>), function<void()>>> m({
      {1, {&Foo::first, printFirst}},
      {2, {&Foo::second, printSecond}},
      {3, {&Foo::third, printThird}},
  });
  struct testCase
  {
    vector<int> input;
    string expected;
  };
  vector<testCase> test_cases = {
      {{1, 2, 3}, "firstsecondthird"},
      {{1, 3, 2}, "firstsecondthird"},
  };
  for (auto &&test_case : test_cases)
  {
    std::stringstream buffer;
    std::streambuf *old = std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());
    Foo foo;
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
      threads.emplace_back(m[i+1].first, foo, m[i+1].second);
    }
    for (auto &&th : threads)
    {
      th.join();
    }
    auto got = buffer.str();
    if (got != test_case.expected)
    {
      printf("input: %s = %s\n",
             CPPUtility::oneDVectorStr<int>(test_case.input).c_str(),
             got.c_str());
      assert(false);
    }
    std::cout.rdbuf(old);
  }
}

int main()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // Test repeatedly to detect any potential race condition
    test();    
  }
}
```

The `oneDVectorStr` is some helper function I write inside a file called `cpputility.h` to help print out the 1D vector, here is the implementation to compile the code above

```
  template <typename T>
  std::string oneDVectorStr(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::string cand = "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
      cand += std::to_string(vec[i]);
      i != vec.size() - 1 ? cand += "," : cand += "";
    }
    cand += "]";
    return cand;
  }
```

I've stared at this code for quite a while but couldn't locate any race condition. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure but I am assuming your semaphores have a race condition. Should not you be using threads via `pthread_t` and synchronize them using a semaphore?

Comment: Why not use `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` instead? You're using `std::thread` already so apparently you have a C++11-compliant compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take a further look at code and realize that there is a subtle bug in my test code: I pass `Foo` object (e.g., `foo`) by copy when create each new thread. However, I really want to have multiple threads sharing the same `Foo` object across multiple threads. Thus, I add `std::ref` to the `foo`:

```
threads.emplace_back(m[i + 1].first, ref(foo), m[i + 1].second);
```

In addition, I print `firstJobDone` and `secondJobDone` semaphore values using `sem_getvalue()` as following:

```
  Foo()
  {
    sem_init(&firstJobDone, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&secondJobDone, 0, 0);
    int value;
    sem_getvalue(&firstJobDone, &value);
    printf("The initial value of the firstJobDone is %d\n", value);
    sem_getvalue(&secondJobDone, &value);
    printf("The initial value of the secondJobDone is %d\n", value);
  }
```

And quite shocking, I have:

```
The initial value of the firstJobDone is 32766
The initial value of the secondJobDone is 32766
input: [1,2,3] = third
Assertion failed: (false), function test, file /home/foo/printInOrder.cc, line 101.
Abort trap: 6
```

Both semaphores are not properly initialized to `0` with LLVM on the Mac that I'm using. However, my implementation invariant insists that both semaphores have to be initilized to `0`. I don't understand why but I'm assuming since `sem_init` is marked as deprecated by LLVM, the behavior is not guaranteed to be correct. Thus, per the comments to my question, I change my implementation using conditional variable and mutex, and everything works fine.